# Can't create links between circles after appending new circles in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

First need to say, that I'm totally new to d3.js (I'm using version 4). For now I have nested object of nodes and trying to draw child elements after clicking parent. And it works partly: I can draw child nodes, but not links from parent circle to child circles. I've got this errors:

> Error: missing: mammal

and

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string 'mammal'

Looks like `source` created successfully, but `target` breaks at the first link and others:

[image]

I'm not sure where the issue is, so I have created a fiddle with all code that I have for now: https://jsfiddle.net/L6c6pxrv/4/

@KEKUATAN suggested me to assign new array to `links`, don't push each item. The result is: https://jsfiddle.net/L6c6pxrv/3/. There is no errors anymore, but looks like links still doesn't know coordinates of source and target.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve after circle click (here I'm using solid array of nodes and links are defined from the very beginning): https://jsfiddle.net/L6c6pxrv/2/

Thanks for any help!

Comment: how to console.log on jsfindle

Comment: @KEKUATAN, the regular `console.log()` is working on jsfiddle, you can see logs in developer tools -> console

Comment: you dont need to forEach>push just write newLinks=links, it will drow but not connected by line, idk but i hope this will give inspiration

Comment: @KEKUATAN, thanks, in this way there is no errors, but links still not connecting circles, I can't figure out why =(

Comment: d3.selectAll('line.link') .attr('x1', function (link) { console.log(link);return link.source.x }) you will find there is no source.x and source.y, idk why never use this chart before, tell me if you know some

Comment: @KEKUATAN, "you will find there is no x and y" - right. but in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/L6c6pxrv/2/ d3.js detects `x` and `y` for links somehow, but in `links` array there is no such properties. In both fiddles `links` arrays are the same, but I have no idea, why d3.js know this properties in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/L6c6pxrv/2/, but doesn't know in this one: https://jsfiddle.net/L6c6pxrv/3/

Comment: that why i said tell me if you know, you must undertand the structure to build each chart on d3, i cant explain why for this case,  idk. why? cos i never use this type of chart before.. sorry

Comment: @KEKUATAN, it's my first time too... Anyway, thanks for your help and spent time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just ask if you need explaination i will try if i can, but not now this time i must go home

like i said before each chart on d3 have structure to understand first before make it, uderstand this structure chart , if you see the data array on working findle you will see there is no children object and id or source betwen 2 array have same value.
i assume your data dont have same data value betwen 2 data array, id and source, that is why you have

> Error: missing: mammal

i add missing mamal to the children object

if you console the node and link, you will find this chart type generating vx and vy

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'vx' on string 'mammal'

is a chain error cos there is no mammal so they cant make vx and vy on id = mammal

**Bug:**

i cant make "M" text on middle of node dancing like other.

**Note:**

d3.forceSimulation() and d3.forceLink() i think this is the core of creating chart like this and this is the reason they generated cildren or vx and vy

**Tips:**

make sure the links data and the nodes data have one same value like id and source so you will get the connection, try dont believe me this is just share what i thing i know, not what i know, try have better teacher to better understanding

```js
var nodes = [
        {
            id: "mammal",
            label: "Mammals",
            fill: 'orange',
            color: '#333333',
            children: [
                        {
                    id: "mammal",
                    label: "Dogs",
                    fill: 'yellow',
                    color: 'orangered'
                },
                {
                    id: "dog",
                    label: "Dogs",
                    fill: 'yellow',
                    color: 'orangered'
                },
                {
                    id: "cat",
                    label: "Cats",
                    fill: 'white',
                    color: 'blue'
                },
                {
                    id: "fox",
                    label: "Foxes",
                    fill: 'green',
                    color: 'black'
                },
                {
                    id: "elk",
                    label: "Elk",
                    fill: 'black',
                    color: 'orangered'
                },
                {
                    id: "insect",
                    label: "Insects",
                    fill: '#333333',
                    color: 'lightblue',
                    children: [
                        {
                            id: "pike",
                            label: "Pikes",
                            fill: 'white',
                            color: 'forestgreen'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: "ant",
                    label: "Ants",
                    fill: 'violet',
                    color: 'white'
                },
                {
                    id: "bee",
                    label: "Bees",
                    fill: 'white',
                    color: 'purple'
                },
                {
                    id: "fish",
                    label: "Fish",
                    fill: 'darkblue',
                    color: 'white'
                },
                {
                    id: "carp",
                    label: "Carp",
                    fill: 'purple',
                    color: 'white'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    var links = [
        // { target: "mammal", source: "dog" },
        // { target: "mammal", source: "cat" },
        // { target: "mammal", source: "fox" },
        // { target: "mammal", source: "elk" },
        // { target: "mammal", source: "insect" },
        // { target: "mammal", source: "ant" },
        // { target: "mammal", source: "bee" },
        // { target: "mammal", source: "fish" },
        // { target: "mammal", source: "carp" }
        // { target: "insect", source: "pike" }
    ];



    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    var svg = d3.select('svg');

    // Append rect and make it draggable
    svg.append('rect').style('width', width * 2).style('height', height * 2).style('fill', 'transparent');
    var dragcontainer = d3.drag()
        .on("drag", function(d) {
            d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + (d.x = d3.event.x) + "," + (d.y = d3.event.y) + ")");
        });
    var g = d3.select('svg').select("g").datum({x: 0, y: 0}).call(dragcontainer);

    var groupWrapper = svg.append('g');



    // Zoom
    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([-Infinity, 100])
        .on('zoom', zoomFn);

    function zoomFn() {
        d3.select('svg').select('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + d3.event.transform.x + ',' + d3.event.transform.y + ') scale(' + d3.event.transform.k + ')');
    }

    d3.select('svg').call(zoom);



    // simulation setup with all forces
    var linkForce = d3
        .forceLink()
        .id(function (link) { return link.id })
        .strength(function (link) { return 0.3 });

    var simulation = d3
        .forceSimulation()
        .force('link', linkForce)
        .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5000))
        .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    var dragDrop = d3.drag().on('start', function (node) {
        node.fx = node.x;
        node.fy = node.y;
    }).on('drag', function (node) {
        simulation.alphaTarget(0.7).restart();
        node.fx = d3.event.x;
        node.fy = d3.event.y;
    }).on('end', function (node) {
        if (!d3.event.active) {
            simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        }
        node.fx = null;
        node.fy = null;
    });



    var linkElements = groupWrapper.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        /**
         * comment below
         */
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1)
        .attr("stroke", "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)");

    var nodeElementsWrapper = groupWrapper.append("g").attr('class', '1');

    var nodeElementsGroup = nodeElementsWrapper
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr('class', 'item')
        .on("click", function(d) {
            console.log("on click", d);
            draw();
        });

    var circleElements = nodeElementsGroup
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 100)
        .attr("fill", function(item) {
            return item.fill;
        })
        .attr("stroke", function(item) {
            return item.color;
        })
        .attr("stroke-width", function(item) {

        })
        .call(dragDrop);

    var textElements = d3.selectAll('g.item')
        .each(function(item, i) {
            d3.select(this)
                .append('text')
                .attr("font-size", 50)
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .attr("alignment-baseline", "central")
                .attr("fill", function () { return item.color })
                .text(function () { return item.id[0].toUpperCase() })

        });



    // Draw children
    function draw() {
        var newLinks = [
            { target: "mammal", source: "dog" },
            { target: "mammal", source: "cat" },
            { target: "mammal", source: "fox" },
            { target: "mammal", source: "elk" },
            { target: "mammal", source: "insect" },
            { target: "mammal", source: "ant" },
            { target: "mammal", source: "bee" },
            { target: "mammal", source: "fish" },
            { target: "mammal", source: "carp" }
        ];

        newLinks.forEach(function(item) {
            links.push(item);
        });

        console.log('LINKS: ', links);

        nodeElementsGroup = nodeElementsWrapper
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes[0].children)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr('class', 'item')
            .on("click", function(d) {
                console.log("on click", d);
            });

        circleElements = nodeElementsGroup
            .data(nodes[0].children)
            .append("circle")
            .attr("r", 100)
            .attr("fill", function(item) {
                return item.fill;
            })
            .attr("stroke", function(item) {
                return item.color;
            })
            .attr("stroke-width", function(item) {

            })
            .call(dragDrop);

        textElements = d3.selectAll('g.item')
            .each(function(item, i) {
            var t = d3.select(this).text()
            if (t=='M'){

            }else{
                d3.select(this)

                    .append('text')
                    .attr("font-size", 50)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("alignment-baseline", "central")
                    .attr("fill", function () { return item.color })
                    .text(function () { 
                    var s =  item.id[0].toUpperCase()       
                    if (s!=='M'){
                    return s
                                        }
                    }).call(dragDrop)
          }
            })          


        linkElements = d3.select('g.links')
            .attr("class", "links")
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1)
            .attr("stroke", "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)");

        // simulation
        simulation.nodes(nodes[0].children).on('tick', function() {
            d3.selectAll('circle')
                .attr('cx', function (node) { return node.x })
                .attr('cy', function (node) { return node.y });
            d3.selectAll('text')
                .attr('x', function (node) { return node.x })
                .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y });
            d3.selectAll('line.link')
                .attr('x1', function (link) { return link.source.x })
                .attr('y1', function (link) { return link.source.y })
                .attr('x2', function (link) { return link.target.x })
                .attr('y2', function (link) { return link.target.y })
        });

     //   simulation.force("link").links(d3.selectAll('line.link')); // "links" instead of d3.selectAll('line.link')
    }



    // Simulation
    simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', function() {
        circleElements
            .attr('cx', function (node) { return node.x })
            .attr('cy', function (node) { return node.y });
        d3.selectAll('text')
            .attr('x', function (node) { return node.x })
            .attr('y', function (node) { return node.y });
        linkElements
            .attr('x1', function (link) { return link.source.x })
            .attr('y1', function (link) { return link.source.y })
            .attr('x2', function (link) { return link.target.x })
            .attr('y2', function (link) { return link.target.y })
    });

    simulation.force("link").links(links);
```

```css
html {
  background-color: gray;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

circle {
  cursor: pointer;
}

text {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

line {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<svg></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution, it works perfectly! But if you can explain what you did, it will be really helpful for me, I'm new in d3.js world

Comment: my english is bad, sorry

Comment: My english too, it's OK. Thank you again!